# Image's dragend event not fired in webkit with tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, tinymce

within the tinymce editor, if I bind the dragend event on images like this

```
_imagePlugin.editor.dom.bind(_imagePlugin.editor.dom.select('img'), 'dragend', function(){console.log('aaaa');});
```

I don't get the console logs in chrome or safari, but I get them in Firefox. The 'drag' events are fired though in all three.

Latest chrome and firefox version, tinymce is 3.4.6

Comment: unfortunatly those events get fired differently in the different browsers, +1 for your question

Comment: `_imagePlugin.editor.dom.select('body')[0].addEventListener('dragend', function(e){console.log(event)}, true)` fires off upon image dragend, but I can't get the image itself from the event, the srcElement and target are both the HTMLBodyElement I specified in the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could get the image from the drag event which will be fired just before the dragend event. You just need to add a drag handler and save the target of that event to use it later on in the dragend handler.

Comment: Indeed, that should work, I'll post the results when I get some time

Comment: used `this.editor.dom.bind(domImgElement, 'drag', _imagePlugin.saveLastImage);` where the image itself was the event's `target` attribute. Thanks!